# Lumen - Authorizable - it is not a trait

Tags: lumen, laravel-passport

Following steps from following url https://bestofphp.com/repo/dusterio-lumen-passport-php-authentication- did authentication of Passport in Lumen. It was works well when `Authorizable` and `Authenticatable` not included/called in user.php file. following code I used to to login and got an error.

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate as Authenticatable;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
// use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Laravel\Passport\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
// use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;




// class User extends Authenticatable {
// class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract {
// class User extends Model {
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract {

// class User extends Authenticatable {
    use HasApiTokens, AuthorizableContract, AuthenticatableContract;
    // use HasApiTokens;


    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'user';
```

response from API

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  App\User cannot use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable - it is not a trait in <b>/var/www/lumen/app/User.php</b> on line <b>32</b><br />
{
    "message": "App\\User cannot use Illuminate\\Contracts\\Auth\\Access\\Authorizable - it is not a trait",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\ErrorHandler\\Error\\FatalError",
    "file": "/var/www/lumen/app/User.php",
    "line": 32,
    "trace": []
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both AuthorizableContract and AuthenticatableContract are not traits.

Please adjust following in your User model

1. move User model to inside app/Models **/var/www/lumen/app/Models/User.php**
2. dont forget to adjust namespace into **namespace App\Models;**
3. incorrect use of Authenticatable, should be
   **use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;**
4. missing Authorizable
   **use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;**
5. as for traits remove yours and use following
   **use HasApiTokens, Authenticatable, Authorizable;**

Try it again to access your User.
You should get correct response.